# Prove that $\ln 2>\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.

Tags: inequality

I have a wrong process in proving $\ln 2>({\frac{1}{2}})^{\ln 2}$, anyway, as an independent question, I want to prove that $\ln 2>\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.

Comment: Calculator gives $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}\approx0.6180$ and $({\frac{1}{2}})^{\ln 2} \approx 0.6185$

Comment: I don't think that $e^{-(\ln 2)^2}<1-(\ln 2)^2$ holds.

Comment: Not sure how $\sqrt 5$ got involved...

Comment: Context would be helpful.  What is the source of this problem?  It is easily solved numerically...is there some reason to imagine that there is a solution that requires no (or little) computation?

Comment: @mathlove You are right!  I use Taylor expansion to solve this question, anyway, Thank you for your help.

Comment: For all reals, $e^x \geqslant 1+x$, so that step is certainly wrong.  Further, you aren't using $2>\frac{\sqrt5-1}2$ anywhere, so unsure what the purpose of this question is.

Comment: You must decide what to prove first.

Comment: And @mathlove is right. There are some false inequalities in your wierd process: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=exp%28-ln%5E2+2%29%3C1-ln%5E2+2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inverse of golden ratio $\phi^{-1}=\frac{\sqrt5 -1}{2}$ has the property $(\phi^{-1})^2+\phi^{-1}=1$. So, to show that $\ln 2>\phi^{-1}$, it is enough to show that $\ln^2 2+\ln 2>1.$ But, since $8>e^2$, we have $\ln2>\frac23$ so that $$\ln^2 2+\ln 2>(\frac23)^2+\frac23=\frac{10}{9}>1.$$

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to proving that $e^{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}} \lt 2, \ $  since $e^x$ is strictly increasing when $x > 0$.

Using the taylor series for $e^x$, we have

$$e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^4}{24} + \ ...$$

$$\lt 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{6}\left(x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + \ ...\right)$$

$$= 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{1}{6}\left(\frac{1}{1-x} - 1 - x - x^2 \right)$$

for $|x| \lt 1$.

Now, let $x = \frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}$.
This is clearly less than $1, $ since $\sqrt{5} \lt 3$.

So using the inequality above, and simplifying yields:

$$e^{\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{2}} \lt \frac{7+2\sqrt{5}}{6}$$

Finally, the RHS can be seen to be less than $2$ by manipulating the fraction to remove the square root.